# Predict model classes only on ROI part in cv2 video frame

Tags: image, numpy, opencv, image-processing, keras

Following is my code with ROI rectangle in it. I want to make predictions of my model based on the image captured in the ROI box only and not the whole image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('Desktop/BCD_nothing_rmsprop.h5')
def sketch_transform(frame):
    return frame

cam_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
upper_left = (50, 50)
bottom_right = (300, 300)
while True:
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()
    #Rectangle marker
    r = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
    rect_img = image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]]
    
    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)
    
    
    #Replacing the sketched image on Region of Interest
    image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]] = sketcher_rect
    classes = model.predict(np.array([rect_img]))
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k ==27:
        break
        
cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to only predict the image inside my rectangle ROI or variable rect_img.

Answer (score 0):

Create resize function before. Then try

```
while True:
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()
    #Rectangle marker
    r = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
    rect_img = image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]]

    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    ##Resize ROI first by create function
    sketcher_rect = resize_function(sketcher_rect,(width,height))


    #Replacing the sketched image on Region of Interest
    image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]] = sketcher_rect
    classes = model.predict(sketcher_rect.reshape(1,width,height,3))
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k ==27:
        break
cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```